# Saving Filter State in an application

Tags: search, filter, application-state

Our application has a case where you can filter a list of projects with a checkbox to show only your projects. A few members of our development team have requested that state of that filter remain between navigations. That is, if I click a result of the filter and then return to the page that is filtering, my filter settings are retained.

We wanted to find the best practices from a user experience perspective for this sort of behavior.

Could someone point me in a good direction on this?

Comment: I don't understand I'm afraid. Your users have asked for a specific feature and have described what they want and why is a benefit, so what exactly do you need from us here?

Answer (score 1):

Retaining the state of the filters is quite a common practice and is handled in the URL of the page using queryString parameters on the code side.

On the UX end, to keep the user experience smooth, the URL could just retain the filters while it is shared, and there is no need to change the UX for this. The filtering experience itself could be improved for one. However, if there is a need to make retaining filters more explicit, here are some examples:

- **Microsoft's PowerBI** has persistent filters. As soon as filters are applied on the report, a button glows in the navbar [reset to default]. Persistent filters can be disabled in the settings. Read more about the UX and feature: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-persistent-filters-in-the-service/
- **Airtable** and **Tableau** also have this feature, but the user has to manually encode the URL field and value, which could be a complex task in itself

  https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046107493-Shared-view-URL-filters
  https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm

Answer (score 0):

You just described the solution in your question. Implement that solution and test it